# Пример создания процедуры  на изменение

Tags: oracle

Киньте, пожалуйста, кто-нибудь пример создания процедуры на изменение.

Comment: На изменение чего когда где и зачем? Если вы знаете что такое процедура очень странно что для вас не очевиден ответ...

Comment: например на изменение адреса (address) по введенному имени (name),хранящегося в таблице Staff...

Answer (score 1):

я oracle вообще не знаю, но в mysql это делается примерно так...
Запрос

```
\d // --устанавливаем делиметр
CREATE PROCEDURE updateAdress(IN username VARCHAR(50), IN newArdess VARCHAR(50))
--тип данных IN параметров должен совпадать с типом в таблице
BEGIN
UPDATE staff SET adress=newAdress WHERE name=username;
END;
//   --подверждаем операцию
\d ; --возвращаем стандартный деллиметр
```

Теперь чтобы вызвать, например из PHP..

```
//    подключение...
$username = 'Вася';
$newAdress = 'ул.Васильковская, д.10';
mysql_query("CALL updateAdress($username, $newAdress)");
//где username имя пользователя  newAdress обновляемое значение
//в данном случае мы обновляем адресс Васе...
```

Важные замечания - в вашем конкретном примере имя должно быть либо `primary key` во избежание изменений сразу несколько записей, либо должен добавится какойто дополнительный параметр, вообще любые операции обновления еденичных записей должны происходить либо по `unique index`, либо по `primary key` либо по уникальному составному индексу.
Еще раз повторюсь с oracle дела не имел, возможно там это делается как-то иначе...(о процедурах)

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужна не процедура, а триггер.
Синтаксис триггера для oracle:

```
CREATE TRIGGER schema.trigger_name 
    AFTER UPDATE 
    ON schema.table_name 
       pl/sql_block
```

Дальше - гугл в руки, смотрите примеры и пишите свой.

Comment: Нет, мне нужна именно процедура)

Comment: "Процедуры на изменение" не бывает. Бывает триггер, который вызывает процедуру.

Comment: И как вы собираетесь вызывать процедуру без использования тригера?<br>
Кстати, а оно вам вообще нужно? Помоему вы пытаетесь лшиь усложнить себе жизнь...

Answer (score 1):

[@AlexWindHope](/users/3545/alexwindhope) в oracle все почти также только без делимитера:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE change_address(name in varchar2(50), new_address in varchar2(100)) is
BEGIN
    UPDATE staff SET adress=newAdress WHERE name=username; 
    COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: буду знать, может быть когда-то да пригодится :)